# How can I download multiple SRR* files at a time when using sratoolkit's fastq-dump?

Tags: data-download, ncbi

I have multiple SRR files to download, and their accession is in a list:

```
SRR9004325
SRR9004326
SRR9004327
```

I read the [NCBI document](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/docs/sradownload/) but don't find how to achieve this using the command "fastq-dump".

And I noticed that if I use the command `prefetch`, I can download from the list file:

```
prefetch --option-file SraAccList.txt
```

So is there any parameter in "fastq-dump" to download accessions stored in a file?

As @terdon said, it is better to use `fasterq-dump`, and the command:
`fasterq-dump --option-file SraAccList.txt` doesn't work. When I try it, I just get the usage message:

```
$ fasterq-dump --option-file SraAccList.txt

Usage:
  fasterq-dump <path> [options]
  fasterq-dump <accession> [options]

Options:
  -F|--format                      format (special, fastq, default=fastq) 
  -o|--outfile                     output-file 
  -O|--outdir                      output-dir 
  -b|--bufsize                     size of file-buffer dflt=1MB 
  -c|--curcache                    size of cursor-cache dflt=10MB 
  -m|--mem                         memory limit for sorting dflt=100MB 
  -t|--temp                        where to put temp. files dflt=curr dir 
  -e|--threads                     how many thread dflt=6 
  -p|--progress                    show progress 
  -x|--details                     print details 
  -s|--split-spot                  split spots into reads 
  -S|--split-files                 write reads into different files 
  -3|--split-3                     writes single reads in special file 
  --concatenate-reads              writes whole spots into one file 
  -Z|--stdout                      print output to stdout 
  -f|--force                       force to overwrite existing file(s) 
  --skip-technical                 skip technical reads 
  --include-technical              include technical reads 
  -M|--min-read-len                filter by sequence-len 
  --table                          which seq-table to use in case of pacbio 
  -B|--bases                       filter by bases 
  -A|--append                      append to output-file 
  --fasta                          produce FASTA output 
  --fasta-unsorted                 produce FASTA output, unsorted 
  --fasta-ref-tbl                  produce FASTA output from REFERENCE tbl 
  --fasta-concat-all               concatenate all rows and produce FASTA 
  --internal-ref                   extract only internal REFERENCEs 
  --external-ref                   extract only external REFERENCEs 
  --ref-name                       extract only these REFERENCEs 
  --ref-report                     enumerate references 
  --use-name                       print name instead of seq-id 
  --seq-defline                    custom defline for sequence:  $ac=accession, 
                               $sn=spot-name,  $sg=spot-group, $si=spot-id,  
                                   $ri=read-id, $rl=read-length 
  --qual-defline                   custom defline for qualities:  same as 
                                   seq-defline 
  -U|--only-unaligned              process only unaligned reads 
  -a|--only-aligned                process only aligned reads 
  --disk-limit                     explicitly set disk-limit 
  --disk-limit-tmp                 explicitly set disk-limit for temp. files 
  --size-check                     switch to control: on=perform size-check 
                                   (default),  off=do not perform size-check,  
                                   only=perform size-check only 
  --ngc <PATH>                     PATH to ngc file 

  -h|--help                        Output brief explanation for the program. 
  -V|--version                     Display the version of the program then 
                                   quit. 
  -L|--log-level <level>           Logging level as number or enum string. One 
                                   of (fatal|sys|int|err|warn|info|debug) or 
                                   (0-6) Current/default is warn. 
  -v|--verbose                     Increase the verbosity of the program 
                                   status messages. Use multiple times for more 
                                   verbosity. Negates quiet. 
  -q|--quiet                       Turn off all status messages for the 
                                   program. Negated by verbose. 
  --option-file <file>             Read more options and parameters from the 
                                   file. 
for more information visit:
   https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/HowTo:-fasterq-dump
   https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/08.-prefetch-and-fasterq-dump

fasterq-dump : 3.0.6
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong with `prefetch`? That's exactly what you need, right? `fastq-dump` (which I believe is obsolete, you should use `fasterq-dump` instead) is to extract fastq files from the SRR, not for downloading.

Comment: @terdon From the documentation: " You can also avoid the prefetch step and download and convert the Run in one step by entering just the Run accession without the .sra extension in your fasterq-dump or sam-dump command".  I just want to download the fastq file.

Comment: OK, so what happens if you run `fasterq-dump --option-file SraAccList.txt`? If you look at the tool's options (run `fasterq-dump` with no arguments), it shows that the option is there.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. But please add that to the question. Have you gotten the command to work correctly for a single file? If so, you could just loop over the accessions.

Comment: @terdon Yes, the options " --option-file" is there, but the description about it is "Read more options and parameters from the file". Emmm, it is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If `fasterq-dump` can't read from a file, you can simply loop over the file yourself:

```
while read srr; do
  fasterq-dump "$srr" -o "$srr".fastq
done < SraAccList.txt
```

That will iterate over your `SraAccList.txt` file and extract the fastqs for each accession. I tested with this command:

```
fasterq-dump SRR9004325 -o ff.fastq
```

And that created files `ff_1.fastq` and `ff_2.fastq`, so you can expect files named like `SRR9004325_1.fastq` and `SRR9004325_1.fastq` if you use the loop above.

You could try and parallelize it but I doubt it is worth it since the bottleneck will always be the download speed.